# rails active record returning incorrect result

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

We have rails (4.2.7.1) app with MySQL (5.7.38) database.

There is an RSpec test. It first adds a record into `storage_links` table and then tests for something.

I put a debugger after the record insertion logic. Doing `StorageLink.last` shows older record not the last inserted one. Although the record exists in database (checked in MySQL console).

I am not sure why active record is returning wrong result.

Anyone know possible reason for this ?

EDIT: Adding main code.

[image]

Adding test code too.
[image]

Issue is in second test case `should return true when limit = 1`

`mass_add` inserts record in a new Thread.

Now in test code, before line 24 I put debugger. And check `StorageLink.count` which shows older count. If I open a rails console in test env now, it shows updated count.

**NOTE: This spec was passing on ruby 2.1.5 but failing on ruby 2.3.5**

Comment: Could you please share the rspec test which you are running.

Comment: There's a common problem... if you do `let(:link){ StorageLink.last }` and you test for change in Rspec, you must reload. So instead do `expect{ save_link}.to change{ link.reload }`

Comment: @SampatBadhe i added both main code and test code. you can check. Thanks!